# Python: Dynamically get type with generic type parameters from string

Tags: python-3.x, generics

Given a type string with generic type parameters, how do I get the type?

E.g. The following works for `Optional`, but not `Optional[str]`.

```
import sys
from typing import Optional

this = sys.modules[__name__]

print(getattr(this, "Optional"))            # typing.Optional
print(getattr(this, "Optional[str]"))       # AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'Optional[str]'
```

In practice, `this` will be another module and the type-string will be a variable only known at runtime.

Edit:
It seems that `eval("Optional[str]")` returns `typing.Union[str, NoneType]`. I thought this was good enough (since `Optional[str] == Union[str, None] = True`), but it only works if `Optional[str]` is imported in the module executing this code (which fails for types used in other modules).

Edit2: Solved by passing globals of module to `eval`: `eval(type_string, vars(module))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of responses, I'm going to answer this myself and ask for comments.

The solution I ended up using was this:

```
eval("Optional[str]", vars(MODULE))
```

The eval function takes a source-string and optionally a dictionary of *globals*. The globals are important if the source string is extracted from a different module. Without it, it would only work for types imported in the module executing `eval(..)`.

A full example could be this:

```
# other.py
from typing import Optional
a: Optional[str] = None
...

# eval_type.py
import other
print(eval("Optional[str]", vars(other)))
```

And if the module was dynamically loaded:

```
import importlib
other = importlib.import_module('other')
print(eval("Optional[str]", vars(other)))
```

I use this exact method for extracting types from Python-docstrings, and evaluating if they match the function-signature. The project is called [pydoctest](https://github.com/jepperaskdk/pydoctest) and the above solution is used here: https://github.com/jepperaskdk/pydoctest/blob/main/pydoctest/utilities.py#L48

I'm not sure how many other use-cases there really are.